# Android how to listen to new Internet Connection

Tags: android, actionlistener

How can I make my app listen to each new Internet Connection, when it's made by an App? What should I do?

I've tried to use BroadcastReciver for android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE, but it doesn't give me any notifications.

```
     <receiver android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592604/android-permission-for-change-intercept-network-settings-and-traffic) don't think normal applications can hold the permissions necessary to do what you want. If you hope to have any success you implementation must be deeper than an ordinary application.

Answer (score 1):

For obvious security reasons, this is impossible. `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` will tell you when the device's Internet connections is up or down, but you cannot spy on other apps.